# How can I drop all the default constraints constraints on a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, constraints

How can I drop all the default constraints belonging to a particular table in SQL 2005?

Comment: I have deleted my answer since I'm not 100% sure and  i am not able to test.

Comment: Your own solution seems ok thouh, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution [from a search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=drop+all+constraints+script&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=): (Edited for Default constraints)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE  @constraintname SYSNAME, @objectid int,
           @sqlcmd         VARCHAR(1024)

DECLARE CONSTRAINTSCURSOR CURSOR  FOR
SELECT NAME, object_id
FROM   SYS.OBJECTS
WHERE  TYPE = 'D' AND @objectid = OBJECT_ID('Mytable')

OPEN CONSTRAINTSCURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM CONSTRAINTSCURSOR
INTO @constraintname, @objectid

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @sqlcmd = 'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_NAME(@objectid) + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @constraintname
    EXEC( @sqlcmd)
    FETCH NEXT FROM CONSTRAINTSCURSOR
    INTO @constraintname, @objectid
END

CLOSE CONSTRAINTSCURSOR
DEALLOCATE CONSTRAINTSCURSOR
```

Comment: changing OBJECT_NAME to PARENT_OBJECT_NAME worked well thanx.

Comment: Good query. I would make a correction though. The declaration of the cursor should be: SELECT NAME, parent_object_id FROM   SYS.OBJECTS WHERE  TYPE = 'D' AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('Mytable')

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I just found it when googling.
A solution that works for me in SQL 2008 (not sure about 2005) without resorting to cursors is below :

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = ''

select @sql = @sql + 'alter table YourTable drop constraint ' + name  + ';'
from sys.default_constraints 
where parent_object_id = object_id('YourTable')
AND type = 'D'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This only deletes the first found constraint (at least that's what it did to me). You have to iterate through all of them.

Comment: @Ioana Marcu: Works for me on a SQL 2008 database. I get a string similar to below for the table called 'Account'   alter table Account drop constraint DF__Account__Account__4865BE2A;alter table Account drop constraint DF__Account__Account__4959E263 i.e. a bunch of concatenated drop statements

Comment: @IoanaMarcu the select statement iterates and concatentes them all into one stirng

Comment: This does not answer the asked question

Answer (score 0):

Script posted by gbn does not work for me, so I'm using a modified version:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE  @DfId INT, @TableId INT,
         @SqlCmd    VARCHAR(1024)

DECLARE DFCONSTRAINTCUR CURSOR FOR
SELECT [parent_object_id] TABLE_ID, [object_id] DF_ID
FROM   SYS.OBJECTS
where parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('<table name>') 
and [TYPE] = 'D' 

OPEN DFCONSTRAINTCUR

FETCH NEXT FROM DFCONSTRAINTCUR
INTO @TableId, @DfId

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @sqlcmd = 'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_NAME(@TableId) + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + OBJECT_NAME(@DfId)
    EXEC(@sqlcmd)
    FETCH NEXT FROM DFCONSTRAINTCUR
    INTO @TableId, @DfId
END

CLOSE DFCONSTRAINTCUR
DEALLOCATE DFCONSTRAINTCUR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @TableName VarChar(Max), @ConstraintName VarChar(Max), @SqlQuery nVarChar(Max)
Declare Cursor1 Cursor Local For Select ST.[name] AS "Table Name", SD.[name] AS "Constraint Name"
FROM sys.tables ST Inner Join sys.syscolumns SC ON ST.[object_id] = SC.[id] 
Inner Join sys.default_constraints SD ON ST.[object_id] = SD.[parent_object_id] And SC.colid = SD.parent_column_id 
ORDER BY ST.[name], SC.colid
    Open Cursor1 Fetch Next From Cursor1 Into @TableName, @ConstraintName
        While @@Fetch_Status = 0 Begin
            Set @SqlQuery = 'Alter Table ' + @TableName + ' Drop Constraint ' + @ConstraintName
            Print @SqlQuery
            Execute (@SqlQuery)
            Fetch Next From Cursor1 Into @TableName, @ConstraintName
        End
    Close Cursor1;
Deallocate Cursor1;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -4):

Just why do you want to do this? Dropping constraints is a pretty drastic action and affects all users not just your process. Maybe your problem can be solved some other way. If you aren't the dba of the system, you should think very hard about whether you should do this. (Of course in most systems, a dba wouldn't allow anyone else the permissions to do such a thing.)

Comment: I am using Several fields that need to support Unicode and I dont find any other way of doing this. therefore I am changing the datatype of the columns and in process droping the constraints and creating them again.......

Comment: This is not an answer as far as I can tell. More of a warning which would be better given by way of a comment?